# SQL join which returns rows where the columns being joined on do not contain any common values

Tags: sql, join

I am creating a booking system for a company which offers driving experiences. This company hires out cars for the customers to drive during a driving session. I have a driving session booking table, which stores each booking; a driving session table, which contains the date and time of each driving session; and a car table, which contains each car that the company can hire out. The driving session booking table is linked to the driving session table by a foreign key, and likewise to the car table by another foreign key.

To give the customer a list of which cars they can drive in the driving session they have picked, I would like to perform an SQL query which pulls up the records in the car table which **are not** linked to any driving session bookings for a particular driving session.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    tbl_car 
SOME-EXCLUDING-JOIN 
    tbl_driving_session_booking ON tbl_driving_session_booking.FK_CarID = tbl_car.PK_CarID 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_driving_session ON tbl_driving_session_booking.FK_DrivingSessionID = tbl_driving_session.PK_DrivingSessionID 
WHERE 
    tbl_driving_session.PK_DrivingSessionID = some_value;
```

Is there any join which would enable me to do this? Else, is there any other way that I could find the cars which are **not being used** in a single query to the database?

Thanks in advance, LC.

Answer (score 0):

The query you want uses `left outer join`:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM tbl_car c left outer join
     tbl_driving_session_booking dsb
     ON dsb.FK_CarID = c.PK_CarID left outer join
     tbl_driving_session ds
     ON dsb.FK_DrivingSessionID = ds.PK_DrivingSessionID and
        ds.PK_DrivingSessionID = somevalue
WHERE ds.PK_DrivingSessionID is null;
```

Note that your condition is moved to the `on` clause for the join.  If there is no match, then the id in the table will be `NULL`.

I also added reasonable table aliases to the query to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use left joins and subquery for detecting available cars.

```
    SELECT * from 
    (SELECT 
    tbl_car.*,  tbl_driving_session_booking.FK_DrivingSessionID as flag
    FROM 
    tbl_car 
    left join
    tbl_driving_session_booking ON tbl_driving_session_booking.FK_CarID =   tbl_car.PK_CarID 
    left join 
    tbl_driving_session ON tbl_driving_session_booking.FK_DrivingSessionID = tbl_driving_session.PK_DrivingSessionID 
    WHERE 
    tbl_driving_session.PK_DrivingSessionID = some_value)
    where flag is null;
```